# Can not select the radio button with value using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

I need one help .I need to check radio button and set the value using Jquery/Javascript.I did something but its not working.

```
<input type="radio" name="con" id="con" value="" onClick="checkCon();">Country
<button type="button" id="btn">Check</button>
```

```js
document.getElementById('btn').onclick=function(){   
    var condata='123';
    $("input[name=con][value=" + condata+ "]").prop('checked', true).trigger('click');
}
```

Here when user will click on check button it can not check the check box and can not set the value.Please help me.

Comment: can you explain more about it ?

Comment: Your name and id are the same, ids should be unique

Comment: i made id unique still same issue.

Comment: First of all do you checked are you getting click event of button?

Comment: yes,When user will click on button it should checked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this, it can help:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
   <head>
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">          </script>
 <script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
    var condata = '123';
    $("#btn").click(function(){
       $('#con').val(condata).prop('checked', true).trigger("click");
    });
 });
 function checkCon()
  {
     alert($('#con').val());
  }
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>

    <input type="radio" name="con" id="con" value="" onClick="checkCon();">Country
    <button type="button" id="btn">Check</button>


   </body>
 </html>
```

this code is working I've checked this, you can also try

its probably because you are mixing up `javascript` and `jQuery` , either you should use `jQuery` or `JavaScript`. Hope the above code help. and make sure you have added jQuery library before using this code

Comment: But i have to trigger one click event there.Check my code.

Comment: then you can append `.trigger("click")` after `.prop()` event

Answer (score 0):

```
You have to use the cotes.
```

[Reference](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-attribute-selector/)

```
$("input[name='con'][value='" + condata+ "']").prop('checked', true).trigger('click');
```

Comment: @satya why you need the trigger ? Pls try to get the selector itself and see if the query worked.

Answer (score 0):

It's clear that there's no radio button with value '123'.

Note 1 : You don't need to prop and trigger at the same time, just prop or trigger the click events.

```
$("input[name=con][value=" + condata+ "]").trigger('click');
```

Note 2 : Click trigger automatically change the radio button properties. If you want to force it checked, do something like this.

```
$("input[name=con][value=" + condata+ "]").on('click', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $(this).prop('checked', true);
});
```

Comment: i checked your line but still issue is same.

Comment: Please check Note 2. :D

Comment: I used note-2 but still same issue.

Answer (score -1):

```
<input type="radio" name="con" id="con" value="" onClick="checkCon();">
```

Your radio button don't have value="123"
    That is why it's not getting checked.
This is the corrected tag

```
<input type="radio" name="con" id="con" value="123" onClick="checkCon();">
```

and it will work as intended

Comment: I need to set the value dynamically.